# Entity Framework не могу понять

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

У меня есть БД. Вот скрин структуры таблицы "Товары":

[image]

Поля CategotyId и ProviderId привязаны к полям Id у таблиц Categories и Providers соответственно.
У меня есть классы:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public Provider Provider { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Итак вопрос: всё работает прекрасно, но **как мне сделать, что бы поля Product.Category и Product.Provider определялись автоматически?**. То есть, что бы при работе с бд через контекст автоматически присваивались значения всем полям и объектам.

P.S. Я использую MySQL и библиотеку Pomelo.EntityFrameworkcore.Mysql

Comment: `var products = dbContext.Products.Where(p=>/*ваше условие*/).Include(p=>p.Provider).Include(p=>p.Category).ToList();`?

Comment: @tyn32167 да, это, я думаю, сработает, но есть ли способ это как то сделать автоматически через атрибут или что то ещё, так как при обновлении бд это ж придёться каждый раз писать

Comment: Заверните это в метод и все дела.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо